# Is solve(a, a) and solve(a) %*% a different?

Tags: r

I made a simple example to study solve(), but it looks that it doesn't work.

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 2, 1, -1), 2, 2, byrow=T)
solve(a, a)
solve(a) %*% a
```

solve(a, a) does work, and I thought the same result will be printed when I run
solve(a) %*% a.

But it doesn't work.

What's wrong?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Roland I think those two sentences should make the same result, but they don't. When I run solve(a) %*% a, the result value is not normal. The result is as follows: 
     [,1]         [,2]
[1,]    1 1.110223e-16
[2,]    0 1.000000e+00

Comment: Inform yourself regarding precision of floating point arithmetics. 1e-16 is basically a zero. Solving the equation system is more precise than the matrix inversion approach.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you should have exactly the same results, but numerically there would be some precision variations.

```
> norm(solve(a, a) - solve(a) %*% a, "m")
[1] 1.110223e-16
```

and you will see the max entry-wise deviation.

---

If you want to check if two results are equal, you can try `all.equal` (thanks for @Ben Bolker's comment)

```
> all.equal(solve(a, a), solve(a) %*% a)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: or `all.equal(solve(a,a), solve(a) %*% a)` (TRUE)